# How can I tell a Linux process to use a file as its entire heap?

Tags: c, linux, file, heap-memory

Say I have a 10MB file on my hard drive. Say I also have a C program and it mallocs a bunch of data and sets various bytes. Is it possible for me to tell this program to target this file as though it were the only memory available on the system, thus redirecting malloc calls to allocate from the 10MB file instead of my system's real memory?

Comment: No it's not really possible. And certainly not desirable as it would make performance of your application go down the dump. You can *memory map* the file on the other hand, and use it as a *part* of your virtual address-space.

Comment: Say, you can. But what is the use case?

Comment: You can override calls to malloc/realloc/calloc/free with symbol interposition (i.e. LD_PRELOAD) and provide an implementation, which returns addresses pointing into a previously mmapp()ed file.

Comment: I agree with @IterAtor, what is the use-case for this? What is the *actual* and *real* problem you want to solve? This has the undeniable smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So that's why http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: You can override the malloc/calloc/realloc/free symbols with interposition (another library or LD_PRELOAD) but a libc implementation, as provider for the allocator functions can keep using the standard allocator regardless of the overrides. You also won't be able to stop other library functions (wheteher in libc or elsewhere) from allocating from making direct syscalls to mmap or sbrk.

Comment: This is not an XY problem. I want to do this because I want to do this.

Comment: Then you should update your question to explicitly state that this is only for curiosity and not for a real use-case. ("I want to do this because I want to do this" isn't really a valid use-case otherwise). And remember, curiosity killed the cat... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not straightforwardly possible to redirect all memory allocation to a mapped file, without editing glibc. However, there is [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/), which allows you to use a *differently named but equivalent* function to allocate from a file. (You could just `#define malloc dmalloc`, but that wouldn't affect libraries, and could screw up other headers.)